# Bug in .Net's LINQ, or me missing something?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I had a strange bug i don't understand, and changing LINQ's IEnumerable to list half way through fixed it, and i dont understand why

Not Real the Code, but very similar
The code below doesn't work:

```
// an IEnumerable of some object (Clasess) internally an array
var ansestors = GetAnsestors();

            var current = GetCurrentServerNode();

            var result = from serverNode in ansestors
                         select new PolicyResult
                                    {
                                      //Some irrelevant stuff 
                                        OnNotAvailableNode = NodeProcessingActionEnum.ContinueExecution,
                                    };

            var thisNode = new PolicyResult
            {
                //Some irrelevant stuff 
                OnNotAvailableNode = NodeProcessingActionEnum.ThrowException,
            };

            result = result.Reverse();
            result = result.Concat(new List<PolicyResult> { thisNode });

            result.First().OnNotAvailableNode = NodeProcessingActionEnum.ThrowException;

            // When looking in the debugger, and in logs, the first element of the
            // result sequence has OnNotAvailableNode set to ContinueExecution
            // Which doesnt make any sense...
```

But when i change the ending to the following it works:

```
        result = result.Reverse();
        result = result.Concat(new List<PolicyResult> { thisNode });

        var policyResults = result.ToList();
        var firstPolicyResult = policyResults.First();

        firstPolicyResult.OnNotAvailableNode = NodeProcessingActionEnum.ThrowException;
        return policyResults;
```

All the types here are classes (reference types) except NodeProcessingActionEnum which is an enum.

Is this a bug?

Me missing something crucial about LINQ?

Help?

Comment: Doesn't `Reverse()` return void ? Do you not get an error *cannot convert void to .....*

Comment: @V4Vendetta http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497.aspx

Comment: He said it wasn't working code...

Comment: @HenkHolterman That line is copy pasted from the code.
Enumerable.Reverse() returns an new reversed collection that is a copy of the original...

Comment: @AK_ Oooops thanks, i thought there was a `ToList` somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`result.First()` executes the (deferred / lazy) query.

That line will set the value OK but when you use `result` later the query will be executed *again*.

Later you are looking at a newly fetched copy. The fact that it is different lets me assume that `GetAnsestors()` is also lazily evaluated and is not an in memory `List<>`

This means that `ToList()` is a worthwhile optimization as well as a fix.  Note that after the ToList you can also use

```
 var firstPolicyResult = policyResults[0];
```

Comment: I think you should rephrase your answer, to be more clear if anyone else googles this question. To say that every time the LINQ IEnumerable is evaluated it executes the first factorizing select, and that both First() and the later enumeration, each evaluate it. so each sees a different collection.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The problem is that running `First` on your IEnumerable removes it from the enumerator so you've then checking the next element.</strike> Actually I've changed my mind - that's probably not it. This solution might be worth a shot, though.

You could wrap the IEnumerable with something which makes the change for you, e.g. using [the `Select` override which accepts an index too](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx):

```
var modifiedResults = results.Select((r, index) => {
    if (index == 0) {
        // This is the first element
        r.OnNotAvailableNode = NodeProcessingActionEnum.ThrowException;
    }
    return r;
});
```

(untested) should do the trick.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying.
Why should calling Firs() on result change it?
its IEnumerable not IEnumerator...